# Onclick Button hide row forever in GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to hide/delete a specific row from gridview when user clicks a button. The gridview should not display the hidden/deleted row even if the page is refreshed or loaded for the second time. The data deleted on the gridview should not affect the database.

My Aspx Code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="frontimage" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="485px" Width="100%"  >
            <asp:table runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <h1>Approve or Reject Subjects</h1>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:table>

        <asp:Table runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                   Course:
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell>

            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>



        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Registration_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" PageSize="50"  >
            <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Approve" 
            CommandName="Select"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Registration_ID" SortExpression="Registration_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Registration_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Registration_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student_ID" SortExpression="Student_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Student_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Student_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Semester_ID" SortExpression="Semester_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Semester_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Semester_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="Course">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Course") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Course") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject1" SortExpression="Subject1">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject1") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject2" SortExpression="Subject2">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject2") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject2") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject3" SortExpression="Subject3">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject3") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject3") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject4" SortExpression="Subject4">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject4") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject4") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject5" SortExpression="Subject5">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject5") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject5") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject6" SortExpression="Subject6">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject6") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject6") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject7" SortExpression="Subject7">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subject7") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectName">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject7") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TotalCreditHours" SortExpression="TotalCreditHours">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalCreditHours") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalCreditHours") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Subject Registration SystemConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Registration_ID], [Student_ID], [Semester_ID], [Course], [Subject1], [Subject2], [Subject3], [Subject4], [Subject5], [Subject6], [Subject7], [TotalCreditHours] FROM [Registration]" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Registration] WHERE [Registration_ID] = @original_Registration_ID AND [Student_ID] = @original_Student_ID AND [Semester_ID] = @original_Semester_ID AND [Course] = @original_Course AND (([Subject1] = @original_Subject1) OR ([Subject1] IS NULL AND @original_Subject1 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject2] = @original_Subject2) OR ([Subject2] IS NULL AND @original_Subject2 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject3] = @original_Subject3) OR ([Subject3] IS NULL AND @original_Subject3 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject4] = @original_Subject4) OR ([Subject4] IS NULL AND @original_Subject4 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject5] = @original_Subject5) OR ([Subject5] IS NULL AND @original_Subject5 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject6] = @original_Subject6) OR ([Subject6] IS NULL AND @original_Subject6 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject7] = @original_Subject7) OR ([Subject7] IS NULL AND @original_Subject7 IS NULL)) AND [TotalCreditHours] = @original_TotalCreditHours" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Registration] ([Registration_ID], [Student_ID], [Semester_ID], [Course], [Subject1], [Subject2], [Subject3], [Subject4], [Subject5], [Subject6], [Subject7], [TotalCreditHours]) VALUES (@Registration_ID, @Student_ID, @Semester_ID, @Course, @Subject1, @Subject2, @Subject3, @Subject4, @Subject5, @Subject6, @Subject7, @TotalCreditHours)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Registration] SET [Student_ID] = @Student_ID, [Semester_ID] = @Semester_ID, [Course] = @Course, [Subject1] = @Subject1, [Subject2] = @Subject2, [Subject3] = @Subject3, [Subject4] = @Subject4, [Subject5] = @Subject5, [Subject6] = @Subject6, [Subject7] = @Subject7, [TotalCreditHours] = @TotalCreditHours WHERE [Registration_ID] = @original_Registration_ID AND [Student_ID] = @original_Student_ID AND [Semester_ID] = @original_Semester_ID AND [Course] = @original_Course AND (([Subject1] = @original_Subject1) OR ([Subject1] IS NULL AND @original_Subject1 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject2] = @original_Subject2) OR ([Subject2] IS NULL AND @original_Subject2 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject3] = @original_Subject3) OR ([Subject3] IS NULL AND @original_Subject3 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject4] = @original_Subject4) OR ([Subject4] IS NULL AND @original_Subject4 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject5] = @original_Subject5) OR ([Subject5] IS NULL AND @original_Subject5 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject6] = @original_Subject6) OR ([Subject6] IS NULL AND @original_Subject6 IS NULL)) AND (([Subject7] = @original_Subject7) OR ([Subject7] IS NULL AND @original_Subject7 IS NULL)) AND [TotalCreditHours] = @original_TotalCreditHours">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Registration_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Student_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Semester_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Course" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject4" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject5" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject6" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject7" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_TotalCreditHours" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Registration_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Student_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Semester_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Course" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject4" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject5" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject6" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject7" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TotalCreditHours" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Student_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Semester_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Course" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject4" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject5" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject6" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Subject7" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TotalCreditHours" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Registration_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Student_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Semester_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Course" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject4" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject5" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject6" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Subject7" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_TotalCreditHours" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>


        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Subject Registration SystemConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [SubjectName] FROM [Subjects]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


       <asp:Table runat="server">
           <asp:TableRow>
               <asp:TableCell>
                   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Back" />
               </asp:TableCell>
           </asp:TableRow>
       </asp:Table>


    </asp:Panel>
```

My Behind Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Subject_Registration_System_for_IUMW
{
    public partial class Approve_or_Reject : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=User-PC\\User;Initial Catalog=Subject Registration System;Integrated Security=True");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["username"] != null)
            {
                Label1.Text = Session["username"].ToString();

            }


            con.Open();


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Course FROM Subjects", con);
            DDL1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DDL1.DataValueField = "Course";
            DDL1.DataTextField = "Course";
            DDL1.DataBind();



            con.Close();


        }



    }
}
```

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: You can change specific column value as `status=0`  in button click. And select `... where status != 0`

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you are saying. Can you please help me by giving a sample code or an example. Thank you.